# A pattern for caching

Tags: design-patterns, caching

If I have to make a web service to provide access to a dictionary, i guess it's a good idea not to fire SQL query on each request, but instead keeping the previous results in memory and access the DB only when the entry hasn't been requested until now.

But this way, my dictionary will increase and ends up with the full SQL-table in memory.

I was searching for a kind of cleaning pattern of the dictionary based on the frequency of usage of each entry. But the "last access time" isn't a good way to do it, nor the hit number since it will be growing with time and does not reflect the average current usage of the entries of my dictionary.

Is there a way to know which entries to discard to spare the DB access has much as possible?

Comment: how do you define "average current usage" ?

Answer (score 0):

There a a number of open source products that solve exactly this problem. I have good experience with [memcached](http://memcached.org/) and [redis](http://redis.io/) for a site with high load.

Answer (score 0):

Most common is "LRU", which stands for "Least Recently Used".  This is the "last access time" you refer to, which works quite good in practice.

Wikipedia has many examples of different strategies, perhaps you can find one that works for you:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Examples

Answer (score 0):

"my dictionary will increase and ends up with the full SQL-table in memory" - how do you define full SQL-Table in memory. Is is possible for you to define a fixed memory size?
If yes, then you could probably create a Priority Queue of that fixed size.
The first element to pop out should be the one which is least frequently hit, you can do that by using Comparable/Comparator Interface.
When the queue is full and you have to insert an incoming element, just trigger queue.pop() and then insert your incoming element. This way you can keep cleaning the least frequently used ones.